# Is Asynchronous file IO thread safe?

Tags: .net, file-io, asynchronous, filestream

Is asynchronous file IO like FileStream.BeginWrite thread safe? If not, then it need to wrap with "SyncLock", that's mean it is still blocking thread.

Comment: Can you provide an example which makes you think it isn't thread safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileStream.BeginWrite` already starts a new thread to access the files. You don't need to start the `FileStream.BeginWrite` on a separate thread (because that will be thread in a thread). On the other hand, multiple `FileStream.BeginWrite` functions should not be accessing the same file at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

Also if the resource is accessed by multiple threads, it means it is a shared resource and there are plentiful of resources about using them in c#.

Answer (score 1):

FileStream.BeginRead / BeginWrite implementations are asynchronous, but their usage of overlapped I/O is not done in a thread-safe manner.

You can see that BeginRead / BeginWrite do not accept the read / write file position as a parameter, so operations on other threads (such as Seek) may cause the read / write to be at the wrong file position.

If you still aren't convinced, Microsoft's FileStream implementation explicitly specify "This isn't threadsafe." in a comment inside [BeginReadCore](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,2051) & [BeginWriteCore](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,2305).

Bottom line: if you need overlapped I/O that is thread-safe, you'll have to use P/Invoke with ReadFile / WriteFile.